# Can't flatten multidimensional array with lots of duplicates

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, permutation, combinations, flatten

I'm trying to create a script that, based on an input `a??` creates an array of all the combinations and permutations of all words containing an `a` and two other characters from the alphabet.
Values are such as `a`, `ab`, `ba`, `dab`, `bga` etc - as you may see the array contains (or should contain) a weird amount of values.

The problem is that the functions I use in the script outputs even more values with many duplicates.
And for some reason I can not create a flattened array without duplicates. I tried to use `array_unique()` but it doesn't work here. I tried to use `explode()` and `implode()` to flatten the result array, but no success. Even if I succeed to create a string from the values, when I try to transform this string into an array, the result is again the actual multi-dimensional array.

This drives me crazy, and as you see the code, I'm a beginner in PHP.

Any help to transform the actual multidimensional array to a flattened one without duplicates is highly appreciated. An example: actually the array contains 12168 sub-arrays, and only the string `a` occurs 1456 times. What I need is an array that doesn't have sub-arrays and contains each results only one time.

The PHP code is available at [here](http://pastebin.com/QgyN9sDd)
and the output is [here](http://www.lunuledesign.com/stack/stack.php):

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like:

```
$inputString = 'a??';
$array = array();

if (strpos($inputString, 'a') !== false && !in_array($inputString, $array)) {
   $array[] = $inputString;
}

echo '<pre>'; print_r($array); echo '</pre>';
```